# Brookstone Rover Android

Tags: android, adhoc

Okay, please don't yell at me because this COULD be a programming problem. The situation is one very similar to a question that was deleted because it was too hardware specific or something. Anyway, I have a Brookstone Rover. I am trying to use an app that I downloaded to control it. The problem is that Android doesn't support ad-hoc networks which is the kind that the Rover is broadcasting. So... if connect to the Rover with a PC's wireless nic and then connect via wire to a wireless router, can I write some software that will make the computer act as a "router" between the two interfaces of the computer (wired to the router and wireless to the rover)

Would I have to write a Java program that has two sockets? if so, in Java how do you choose which network interface you want your packets to go out on? (Socket programming)

Comment: Thanks all for your input. I am going to try to use Ubuntu's bridging software https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge and see if that will work as a solution. I will let you know how it turns out...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it sounds like you would write a *proxy* program that has two sockets, one connected to your Rover and the other connected to your Android. This is not a "router" in the networking sense (you're not dealing directly with IP packets), but rather a program that has two socket connections to two different networks. The job of this program would be to read anything that comes in on socket A and send it to socket B, and vice versa.

You don't have to "choose" which network interface your packets go out on, as the OS does that for you. You do, however, have to connect to the correct IP address and the OS takes care of the packets.

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of that app and the question that was too hardware-specific was mine. There are software solutions on Windows, such as Connectify. My ideal scenario would be (adapted) DD-WRT firmware on a router. Be aware that every proxy introduces latency which is not nice for remote controlling a robot.